# Reason for buttons on back of frocks

Tags: sources-mekorot, clothing

What is the reason why Lithuanian & chabad style frocks have two buttons on the back of them ?

Comment: Do you have some reason to think there is some Judaism based reason for buttons on clothing? Without such an edit I don't think this is on topic. I have buttons on my shirt too but I don't ask about them here.

Comment: Style..........

Comment: Kaftor vaferach

Answer (score 1):

The formal frock coat, on which they are based, traditionally had two buttons in the back. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frock_coat) about frock coats, which says

> The formal frock coat only buttons down to the waist seam, which is decorated at the back with a pair of buttons.